# Passing children to Angular.js directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm maintaining an old Angular.Js system, which has a lot of repeated code which I'm trying to reduce. Coming from React, one pattern I'm used to is this:

```
function Parent({children}) {
     return (
         <div>
             {children}
         </div>
     )
}
```

Is there a similar pattern in angularjs where I can pass a piece of dynamic (angular responsive) html to a directive/component and use this piece inside the code with a wrapper?

My goal with this is to eliminate a large piece of code that is repeated in every popup of the system which is just the header and the bottom buttons of the popup. How would I go about making a popupcontainer that can be reused with different directives/components within it? I have searched for this, but couldn't find anything specific.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up on how using `transclude` in directives works

Comment: Sounds like you know this, but each bit of reusable HTML can be a directive, which can receive dynamic variables inline `<header data-popupinfo='object'></header>`

Comment: Yes, thank you, I do know this, what I don't know is how to use it in such a way that what is being passed as the object in your example is also a directive. Could I just use <object> within the html of the parent?